# Showing failed re-building development npm/react/gatsy errors in browser

Tags: reactjs, npm, gatsby

I'm doing development work using `gatsby develop`. Basically, this script monitors the source code files and re-builds whenever there are changes.

When the re-build succeeds, the browser automatically refreshes and shows the newly built page. 
However, when the re-build fails, the browser does nothing, and if I were to manually refresh the webpage, it still loads the last working version, leading to confusion as to why my changes are not reflected.

The only way to tell that the re-build failed is by looking at the terminal output of `gatsby develop`, which I often hide in order to maximize screen real estate.

Is there a way to for me to **just look at the browser and code**, and be able to tell that a re-build has failed? The best would be to have the errors show up in the browser, much like the javascript errors, where the re-build was successful, but the code ran into issues in the browser, i.e. TypeErrors, undefined etc.

Thank you.

Comment: what about open dev console in the browser? it shows up error messages when the build has failed.

Comment: Dev console is just the same as CLI, there are often times I just want code and browser.

I did a quick check, it appears my browser does not refresh at times when there is a build failture.

Answer (score 0):

After @gnujoow's comments, I did a quick check and realized that **build failures already show up in the browser**.

For some reason, my browser does not always refresh when there are build failures. Thanks @gnujoow